# Remove outliers from mostly linear data

Tags: regression, outliers, count-data

I have a cumulated sum of battery charges that is mostly extremely linear, apart from some faulty data in the beginning. See this image as an example:

[image: img]

In order to get the most accurate linear regression, I would like to remove the parts that do not show the same general slope of the accurate data. How could I approach this? I cannot assume the date of the beginning of the correct data.

My general ideas:

1. Remove outliers in the underlying "count" data, since the slope is a lot higher in the cumulated sum, showing that there was an unrealistic amount of charges per day.
2. Create a rolling slope/spline fit or something similar and find the most common/median slope for the data.

Any ideas would be very appreciated!

Comment: (1) It would be incorrect to apply most regression techniques to these data, because their cumulative nature imposes *huge* dependencies among them.  Consider modeling the first differences (or, if the times are unequally spaced, point-to-point slopes). (2) A robust linear fitting procedure is likely to do a good job.  (3) Since you really just need to estimate the slope, you can even use simple procedures like a Winsorized mean of the differences or even--as you suggest--compute their median.  Once the slope is estimated, you can adjust the intercept to taste.

Comment: The objective is to extrapolate to a threshold count and get the date when that happens, so I don't think modeling the first differences would help here? Or do you mean that I calculate the first difference and remove those that have too large a difference compared to some value like the median difference?

Comment: Modeling the first differences is essential if you wish to avoid the complexities of directly modeling the interdependencies created by your cumulative series.  With a model for them you simply accumulate the fitted first differences to make your forecast.